# Using private instances in statement Java

Tags: java, oop

I currently am having difficulty trying to use a private instance of a variable for a while test in Java.

The Character variable has a private lon field however I can't use it in my while statement correctly. I want to increment the lon field by one but want to break the loop when it is 3, some help please?

```
while(lon!=3)
{   System.out.println("Try find the treasure. Move up, down, left and right");
    String in2 = s.next();
    if (in2.equals("up"))
        {   Character.goUp(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: have you set getter and setter for lon ?

Comment: This code doesn't ever show `lon` changing. Is that what `goUp` does?

Comment: @vishalgajera yes I do, for the lon i do. I should add lon is a private field for Character

Comment: @CharlesWood apologies, yes. goUp has the lon increment by 1

Comment: And presumably, this code is occurring inside the Character class?  What's `s`? We could really use more information.

Comment: Also, what's happening instead of what you would like to happen? Is `lon` actually getting any bigger?

Comment: s is , I believe a scanner. So the user inputs something into there

Comment: Basically we need to see more code.

Comment: Ok I have managed to  do it and I did in fact have to use the getter method. Might I ask what would be wrong in saying "while (Character.lon!=3) "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your getter method inside while.

```
while(Character.getIon()!=3)
```

Comment: The poster has stated in the comments that he has a getter and setter for `lon`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a dumb statement. Getters are for accessing private variables. I'm going soft from using Groovy :D